# Prove that $\textbf{Int}(Y)$ is the largest open set contained in $Y$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

In Green and Gamelins book "An Introduction to Topology" there is an exercise Id like some feedback on. If $Y$ is a subset of $X$, then prove that $\textbf{Int}(Y)$ is the union of all open subsets of $X$ that are contained in $Y$. I understand the books solution, which is, if we consider each $x \in U$ where $U$ is the union of open subsets in $Y$. There exists a ball $B(x, r) \subset U$, open. So each $x \in U$ is an interior point of $Y$ and $U \subseteq \textbf{Int}(Y)$. But $U$ is the set of all open subsets of $Y$, so $\textbf{Int}(Y)  \subseteq U$ and thus $\textbf{Int}(Y) = U$.

Now, my solution goes as follows. 
Each open subset in $Y$ is a union of open balls. 
Around each point in $\textbf{Int}(Y)$ there exists an open ball, so $\textbf{Int}(Y)$ is open and each open subset of $Y$ is a subset of the union of these open balls. Taking the union of these subsets would exhaust the set of open balls in $\textbf{Int}(Y)$ and we are done.

My question is, is my solution enough?

Comment: Is this in the setting of metric spaces or general topological spaces?

Comment: Woops, it is in the setting of metric spaces. Changed the tag to metric-spaces. Thank you.

Comment: The last sentence ("these subsets would exhaust the set of open balls") is not justified, in my opinion.

Comment: In retrospect, I think I meant: $\mathbf{Int} \ Y$ is open and can, therefore, be represented as a union of open balls contained in $Y$. Considering each and every point of $\mathbf{Int} \ Y$ and creating an open ball around these points and taking the union of these, would ultimately lead to a set being equal to both $\mathbf{Int} \ Y$ and also $U$. 

Does that make my reasoning clearer?